# why the methods /propreties of an interface can be passed in an extension function

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, interface, extension-function

Today I had to use an extension function which had as predicate an Interface, a kind of `Interface.whateverExtensionFunction()` 
and a I had a `class ViewModel () :InterfaceInherithingFromAnotherInterface`.  The architectural idea 
  behind is to maintain my viewModel tidy and delegate some heavy weight to the extension function.
I do not understand why into my ViewModel in whatever method I can call the extension function `FruitColorsInterface.changeColors()` as in the code below into the method `cut()`

I **do not undersand how is possible that effectively into the extension function, I can call the interface method**

If a class implements an interface this is a contract to **implement the methods** of the interface and not too pass an object Interface has happens in this extension class**

```
class testInterface(){

    @Test
    fun testInterface(){
AppleTrim().cut()
    }

}

class AppleTrimViewModel : FruitColorsInterface{
    override val red: String
        get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
    override val green: String
        get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.

    override fun mixColors(): String {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun move3d() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun spinFromTop(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    fun cut(){

        changeColors()
        //FruitColorsInterface.changeColors()//why this is error?

    }
}

interface FruitColorsInterface {
    val red :String
    val green:String

    fun mixColors(): String
    fun move3d()
    fun spinFromTop() :Int

}

fun FruitColorsInterface.changeColors(){
    println("Ehy")
    mixColors()//WHY IS THAT? 

}
```

if I decompile in Java I get a static function where is passed an interface

```
    public static final void changeColors(@NotNull FruitColorsInterface $this$changeColors) {
          Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$changeColors, "$this$changeColors");
          String var1 = "Ehy";
          System.out.println(var1);
          $this$changeColors.mixColors();
       }
//and
   public final void cut() {
      Test_interfaceKt.changeColors(this);
   }
```

Comment: The extension function is accepting any *concrete* object implementing `FruitColorsInterface`. Then it calls `mixColors()` on that object and it will execute the concrete method implemented inside the object. In your case, by calling the extension function, you are passing `this`: it being an instance of `AppleTrimViewModel`, that indeed implements `mixColors()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scope of an extension function you have an instance of the type that it extends (in your example it is `FruitColorsInterface`) available as `this` — an implicit receiver.

Using that `this` instance you can invoke other functions and properties available on that type, no matter whether they are members or extensions.

As to why you can call just `mixColors()` instead of `this.mixColors()` in the extension function body, it's because `this` is available implicitly, same as in the member function bodies, and thus it can be omitted.

Comment: sometimes syntactic sugar make me lose contact with the old java logic, but I forgive kotlin, is pragmatic and fast and I can always see the java code generated if want to understand